# Approval/Denial System using Discord.js

Tags: discord.js, google-forms

**DISCORD.JS**

Hey! So, recently, I was on a server that contained an amazing bot. That was an approval or denial system. So, what would happen for example, somebody would sign a google form and the google script will send the response via a webhook (**I already know that code**) in an embed to a private channel named "awaiting-result", now, the bot will automatically add reactions to the message, for example, ✅ and ❌. Then, a staff member will react with either one of those emojis and it will send to two different channels. If the reaction was a ✅, then the bot will remove all reactions from the original message, copy the exact embed from the google form response, and send it to a channel named "accepted-logs" with a message above it "Your log has been accepted by ${person}". If it was an ❌, it will do the exact same thing as the approved one. I have been trying hard, but cant find it. All I ready need is the bot code, not the form script. So basically, you react, copy the exact embed, send to another channel. Itll be very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of useful links:

1. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#unicode-emojis
2. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors
3. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor

I'm pretty sure you could just store the embed contents in an Object, then you can wait for the collector to collect a ✅ or ❌, check if the user has admin role (e.t.c), and then find the channel the embed needs to be sent too

```
let channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "name");
```

and then you can send the embed to the channel via

```
channel.send(embed);
```

In order to make an embed, you just do:

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
```

And then you can add fields to it (see link #3). Then you can simply just do

```
let approvalChannel  = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name = "admin-approval");
approvalChannel.send(embed);
// Code for reaction collector
```